# Change Default Custom Fields Metabox Name

Tags: title, metabox

I found that the title of the meta box cannot change via the [cctm plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/). It shows "Custom Fields" as default, which is pretty annoying to see.

[Image](http://postimage.org/image/tkoyifph9/)

So I decided to change it in function.php, here is my code :

```
add_filter('add_meta_boxes', 'change_meta_box_titles');
function change_meta_box_titles() {
$wp_meta_boxes['my_post_type']['normal']['core']['cctm_default']['title']= 'Details';}
```

But it failed to work, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `$wp_meta_boxes` array as global:

```
global $wp_meta_boxes;
```

If it still doesn't work try:

```
add_filter('add_meta_boxes', 'change_meta_box_titles');
function change_meta_box_titles() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($wp_meta_boxes);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

to see what's going on (and to check where the title is). You should also **prefix your function names** to prevent a clash with WP or other plug-ins.

Comment: Hi,I added the global $wp_meta_boxes; but still not working, and your function cause me a fatal error where causing fails to access the entire site. i also try prefix, no luck as well.

Comment: There was a missing semi-colon after `global $metaboxes`. I've edited the answer. The prefix won't solve the problem - but it may prevent you encountering another one!

Comment: Waw...it works. I found the correct array circle. Thanks...