# Change Default Custom Fields Metabox Name on cctm plugin

Tags: metabox

i found this thread [Change Default Custom Fields Metabox Name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49479/change-default-custom-fields-metabox-name/49480#comment63463_49480)
and i also want to change this cctm plugin generated Custom Field header to something else,so i tried to add

`global $wp_meta_boxes;`

add_filter('add_meta_boxes', 'change_meta_box_titles');
function change_meta_box_titles() {
$wp_meta_boxes['my_post_type']['normal']['core']['cctm_default']['title']= 'Details';}

to my wordpress functions.php,but it not worked for me,i also tried second code found there,but still not worked for me. Is the wordpress functions.php correct file where to put this code,or is it [cctm plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) plugin functions.php correct and on which line i must add code if correct file is cctm plugin functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) from the Wordpress Codex:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );

function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
  add_meta_box( 
    'myplugin_sectionid',
    __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
    'post' 
  );
}
```

Comment: This did not worked,anyway i found solution other way,i post it here,in case anybody looking for same thing. To change http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager cctm plugin(custom content type manager)default post type header from `Custom Fields` to other name you want,open your costum content type plugin directory - custom-content-type-manager go to includes folder and open StandardizedCustomFields.php file and change default Custom Fields name to name you want http://pastie.org/4534157 (here is correct line,where to change it)